# Logic app connecting to MQ getting message item binary content instead of message item content

Tags: azure-logic-apps

our Logic app connects to MQ and polls messages, for one of hte queue, I am seeing message in below format coming in Message item binary content,

```
{
  "$content-type": "application/octet-stream",
  "$content": "PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiBlbmNvZGluZz0idXRmLTgiPz48bnM0aW9uVGV4dD4KICA8L0V4Y2VwdGlvbj4KPC9uczA6UG9saWN5VXBkYXRlPg==" //truncated value
}
```

How to get value from content in logic app?

Also for other queues message coming in Message item content and able to get text data correctly.

Comment: Looks a lot like [Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64). Not sure if logic apps have a way of decoding it though.

Comment: Yeah you could use the `decodeBase64` function to decode the `$content`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue got resolved after conneccting with MS Helpdesk, need to use string(Message item binary content) when reading messages, this will get decoded.